# find children node from parent in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, pyqt, qt5

I have one QTabWidget and i am dynamically adding tab and toolbutton with the help of below code.

```
QTabWidget *m_tabWidget = new QTabWidget(this);
m_addNewTab = new QWidget(m_tabWidget);
m_addNewGridLayout = new QGridLayout(m_addNewTab);
m_addNewWebView = new QWebView(m_addNewTab);

widget = new QWidget(m_addNewTab);
tb = new QToolButton(widget);
tb1 = new QToolButton(widget);

m_horizontalLayout = new QHBoxLayout(widget);
m_horizontalLayout->addWidget(tb);
m_horizontalLayout->addWidget(tb1);

m_addNewGridLayout->addWidget(m_addNewWebView, 0, 0, 1, 1);
m_tabWidget->addTab(m_addNewTab, QString());
```

After dynamically adding 3-4 tabs i want to get only QToolButton object.
I have used below code to find the children of the parent widget.

```
for (tabCount = 0;tabCount < m_tabWidget->count();tabCount++)
{
    QWidget *tab = m_tabWidget->widget(tabCount);
    QList<QWidget*> widgetList = tab->findChildren<QWidget*>();
    foreach( QWidget* widgetPtr, widgetList )
    {
        qDebug() << "Child Widget" << widgetPtr;
    }
}
```

Above code is only printing the "QWebView" pointer. Why not QToolButton object ? As we have given the parent in QToolButton.

Can someone help  ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You probably need to add `widget` to the tab's `m_addNewGridLayout` layout.

Comment: I have tried to add m_horizontalLayout to m_addNewGridLayout.    After adding below statement it is not working.                    m_addNewGridLayout->addLayout(m_horizontalLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1);

Comment: Not working? What is the error? You need to add the layout to the different  row/column. Use `m_addNewGridLayout->addLayout(m_horizontalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1);` instead.

Comment: Not working in the sense qDebug only print "QWebView" object.

Comment: As per your suggestion, i have tried to add m_addNewGridLayout->addLayout(m_horizontalLayout, 1, 0, 1, 1); but it print all the "QWebView" object available in different tab. It also not printing the required QToolButton object.

Comment: Your code worked fine for me. The output was `Child Widget QWebView(0x2fd1dc20)
Child Widget QWidget(0x2fd1e5d8)
Child Widget QToolButton(0x2fd1e618)
Child Widget QToolButton(0x2fd1e658)`

Comment: @thunga. During addition of the tab it will display but when you navigate to different tab then it will not displayed the child widget. Can you please share the code ?

Comment: It displays them even after changing the tab. [My code](http://hostcode.sourceforge.net/view/4052).

Comment: Thanks for the code. Your toolbutton is inside the tab. I am setting the toolbutton on the tab itself with below function.                         m_tabWidget->tabBar()->setTabButton((m_tabWidget->count() - 1), QTabBar::LeftSide, widget);

Comment: @Neel, I am also getting the 2 `QToolButton` (along with the QWebView and QWidget) with your code. Something else is wrong with your code.

Comment: Well in that case the toolbuttons no longer belong to `m_addNewTab`. By setting `widget` to act as a tab button, the `tabBar` will take ownership of that widget. So the parent tree would now look like this: `m_tabWidget ` => `taBar` => `widget` => `toolButton`.

Answer (score 3):

By setting `widget` as a tab button of the tab bar, the ownership of `widget` will be taken by the tab bar. So your toolbuttons will no longer be any kind of children of `m_addNewTab`. In order to find these buttons, you will have to search the children of the tab bar:

```
    QList<QWidget*> widgetList = m_tabWidget->tabBar()->findChildren<QWidget*>();
```

To make the search easier, set some object names to your tool buttons:

```
    QToolButton *tb = new QToolButton(widget);
    tb->setObjectName("TB");
    QToolButton *tb1 = new QToolButton(widget);
    tb1->setObjectName("TB1");
```